# Toggle all Local Variables in *ngFor From Outside Loop

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, ngfor, angular-ng-if

Let's say I have an *ngFor loop where I define a variable at the local scope like:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <p>{{item.name}}</p>
  <div *ngIf="item.colorVisible">{{item.color}}</div>
  <button (click)="item.colorVisible = !item.colorVisible">Toggle Color</button>
</div>
```

I am looping through an array of objects, so dummy array in typescript would be:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  items = [
    {
      name: 'John',
      color: 'Green'
    },
    {
      name: 'Jim',
      color: 'Blue'
    },
    {
      name: 'Jane',
      color: 'Orange'
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I have a button outside of the loop that toggles all variables and then updates the variable in scope?

Here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9pqjs4?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: What do you mean by "updates the variable in scope"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a boolean property to your component and create a method to loop through your items.

Component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  public allVisible = false;
  items = [
    {
      name: 'John',
      color: 'Green',
      colorVisible: false
    },
    {
      name: 'Jim',
      color: 'Blue',
      colorVisible: false
    },
    {
      name: 'Jane',
      color: 'Orange',
      colorVisible: false
    }
  ]

  toggleAll() {
    this.allVisible = !this.allVisible;
    this.items.forEach((item) => {
        item.colorVisible = this.allVisible;
    });
  }
}
```

Template

```
<button (click)="toggleAll()">Toggle All Colors</button>
```

I [forked your StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j9vtyk).